# Mapping one type to another to use with own algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, c++14

I am currently working on a library that does some computational geometry. In order to visualize the results of my algorithms (and to use them in an interactive setting), I have decided to write a little viewer/tool in `Qt`, but keep the core logic seperated from this viewer. So now I have a `QGraphicsScene` which contains a bunch of different items, however, I am only interested in the `QGraphicsRectItems`:

```
for(auto* item : scene) {
    if(QGraphicsRectItem* c = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(item)) {
        // ... do stuff
    }
}
```

My library currently defines my own type

```
struct rectangle {
    double x,y;
    double w,h;
};
```

and algorithms that work on them. Imagine I have a method

```
void layout(std::vector<rectangle>& rs) { ... }
```

which takes a collection of arbitrarly positioned `rectangles` and places them all next to each other.

I now want to use this algorithm with my `QGraphicsRectItems` in the scene. How would you do this? I was thinking that I could convert the `QGraphicsItems` to `rectangles`, store the rectangles in a vector and use a `std::unordered_map<rectangle*,QGraphicsRectItem*>` to keep track of which item they belong to. After I am done processings the `rectangles` I could iterate over the vector and apply the changes to the items in the scene.

Is this the way to go? How would you solve this problem? Maybe my design is flawed from the beginning?

Comment: Does `layout` just change the values, or does it move the rectangles index around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scene has stable ordering, and layout edits entries without "reordering" them, iterate over the scene.

Stuff a rectangle into a vector for each element in the scene using push back.

Do layout.

Reverse the vector.

Iterate over the scene, poping the new location off the end of the vector for each scene element.

You could mess with pointers or indexes, but the above acts as a one-pass queue and works.

You start with the scene having:

```
qA qB qC qD qE qF qG
```

we then create a vector of rects:

```
rA rB rC rD rE rF rG
```

we process them to lower case:

```
ra rb rc rd re rf rg
```

then reverse:

```
rg rf re rd rc rb ra
```

Now we iterate over qt scene and pop:

```
current | stack [top of stack]
qA:ra   | rg rf re rd rc rb [ra]
qB:rb   | rg rf re rd rc [rb]
qC:rc   | rg rf re rd [rc]
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, not all of the algorithms are stable. I should have mentioned that from the beginning.

Comment: @j.dog then your problem cannot be solved as described: pointers to elements in a vector are not stable either.  Augment your layout functions to track identity.

Comment: Of course, now I feel stupid. Thank you for pointing this out.